# How to display console output in output window in Visual Studio Addin?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-addins

I am developing a Visual Studio plugin. It will automatically generate and run a command line. If I run the command in the shell, it could generate some logs during running.

However, I want to hide the shell window and display the logs in the Visual Studio Output Window. Is there a way to implement this?

Here's my code to run the command:

```
var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c"+command; 
process.Start();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect Console.Write... Methods to Visual Studio's Output Window While Debugging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518509/redirect-console-write-methods-to-visual-studios-output-window-while-debuggi)

Answer (score 0):

according to this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518509/redirect-console-write-methods-to-visual-studios-output-window-while-debuggi)

> Change application type to Windows before debugging. Without Console window, Console.WriteLine works like Trace.WriteLine. Don't forget to reset application back to Console type after debugging.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

StreamReader stringBackFromProcess = process.StandardOutput;

Debug.Write(stringBackFromProcess.ReadToEnd());

// or

Console.Write(stringBackFromProcess.ReadToEnd());
```

Comment: `string.ToString()` really?

Comment: @leppie, was a simple mistake. Fixed.

Comment: Thank for your reply. So if I use Debug.Write, the output will only display in the debug mode. Is there another way to display it? The plugin won't work in the debug/trace mode when users run it.

Comment: I'm not sure since I haven't dabbled into extending VS but here are some resources that may be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773880/how-do-i-write-to-the-output-window-in-visual-studio-2010-addin https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht6z4e28.aspx  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hk6fby3.aspx https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsoutputwindow.aspx https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166236.aspx